# 'make -n' equivalent for ant

Tags: ant, makefile

According to the man page of make, -n option does the following job:

```
Print the commands that would be executed, but do not execute them.
```

I am looking for an option which acts the same in Apache Ant.

Comment: A very reasonable request.  It's surprising that ant lacks this basic capability.

Answer (score 2):

Horrific, but here it is.  We can hack the targets at runtime using some code inside a `<script>` tag*.  The code in `do-dry-run` below sets an `unless` attribute on each of your targets, and then sets that property so that none of them executes.  Ant still prints out the names of targets that are not executed because of an `unless` attribute.

*(JavaScript script tags seem to be supported in Ant 1.8+ using the Oracle, OpenJDK and IBM versions of Java.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="build">

    <target name="targetA"/>
    <target name="targetB" depends="targetA">
        <echo message="DON'T RUN ME"/>
    </target>
    <target name="targetC" depends="targetB"/>

    <target name="build" depends="targetB"/>

    <target name="dry-run">
        <do-dry-run target="build"/>
    </target>

    <macrodef name="do-dry-run">
        <attribute name="target"/>
        <sequential>
            <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[

                var targs = project.getTargets().elements();
                while( targs.hasMoreElements() ) {
                    var targ = targs.nextElement();
                    targ.setUnless( "DRY.RUN" );
                }
                project.setProperty( "DRY.RUN", "1" );
                project.executeTarget( "@{target}" );

            ]]></script>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

</project>
```

When I run this normally, the `echo` happens:

```
$ ant
Buildfile: build.xml

targetA:

targetB:
     [echo] DON'T RUN ME

build:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

But when I run dry-run, it doesn't:

```
$ ant dry-run
Buildfile: build.xml

dry-run:

targetA:

targetB:

build:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Ant has no dry-run option as make or maven have. But you could run the ant file step by step  it in debugging mode under eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

No I belive. There is no such way by default in Ant. And many unstisfying attempts you would find on google. But I have searched once and was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a useful feature, but not easily implemented.

Make and ANT are architecturally quite different. ANT doesn't run external OS commands, instead, most ANT "tasks" execute  within the same Java thread.

It would be possible to emulate a "dry run" as follows:

```
<project name="Dry run" default="step3">

    <target name="step1" unless="dry.run">
        <echo>1) hello world</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="step2" depends="step1" unless="dry.run">
        <echo>2) hello world</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="step3" depends="step2" unless="dry.run">
        <echo>3) hello world</echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

Running ANT as follows will print the target name but won't execute the enclosed tasks:

```
$ ant -Ddry.run=1

Buildfile: build.xml

step1:

step2:

step3:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a special target in your buildscript that does some echoing only i.e. to check
 whether properties, path .. are resolved correctly.
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6724412/130683 for a similar question answered.
For checking the details of your ant installation use `ant -diagnostics`